# Data coming in Service Response but showing 'undefined' from where it is called - JavaScript | React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, asynchronous, axios

I am calling an API which in turns gives me data back. When I am trying to store that data in variable and then console.log, the result is `undefined`. Why is it happening? How to fix this?

**someService.js**

```
  getItems: () => {
    axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
    .then( response => {
         console.log(response.data); //gives me an array of 10 items
         return response.data;
    })
  }
```

**someReducer.js**

```
case "GET_ITEM_LIST": {
    let data = getItemsAPI.getItems();
    console.log(data); //gives undefined
    return {
        ...state,
        items: data
    }
}
```

Comment: A side note: reducers should be pure functions, and shouldn't have any side effects such as network requests

Answer (score 1):

With your case, you fetching API from server as `asynchronous`:

Try to you `async/await` like this:

```
export default {
   fetch: async (state, { type, payload }) => {
       // ....
       case "GET_ITEM_LIST": {
          let data = await getItemsAPI.getItems();
          console.log(data); // you will see data here
          return {
             ...state,
             items: data
          }
       }
       // ....

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return promise and await for result as its async. Notice return before axios that returns promise that you can work on. (I'm editing in mobile and I guess formatting is bad. If it worked, will update later)

`getItems: () => {
    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
    .then( response => {
         console.log(response.data); //gives me an array of 10 items
         return response.data;
    })
  }`

Then, `await getItems()` or `getItems().then()` wherever you need.